# Why Windows 10 could not be installed on Pentium D 945 processor?

Tags: windows, windows-10

System:

- Main board gigabye 945pl-s3
- CPU Intel Pentium D 945 (dual core 3.40 GHz)
- CPU supports nx feature and enabled from BIOS.

I cannot install Win10 (my current OS is Win7-x86 pro). The Win10 setup says "your processor doesn't support the nx feature" (nx = disable exe bit; for virus protection).

Processor Specification: http://ark.intel.com/products/27520/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-945-4M-Cache-3_40-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: Have you tried to simply enable the nx feature? I suggest you enable the feature, install 64-bit Windows 7 installation, then upgrade that.

Comment: in order to be able to run Windows 10 (or Windows 8/8.1), you need a processor that supports PAE, NX, and SSE2. http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-will-your-pc-run-it/

Comment: From my link-"Download and run a handy utility called CPU-Z. Look under Instructions and if you see SSE2, EM64T (indicates the processor has support for PAE) and either VT-d or VT-x (which is what's needed for NX support) then you're ready to rock." Your processor does not support VT-x

Comment: @Moab you mix something here. VT-x is not required for hosts, only when you try to use Hyper-V. Here also SLAT is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try messing with the NX feature in the BIOS/UEFI. If it's ON turn OFF and vice-versa.

I heard there's a way to bypass the NX verification by simply installing the OS from a CD instead of USB. Albeit if the bug persists you won't be able to boot afterwards, I'd say it's worth a try though.

I would also try re-flashing the BIOS/UEFI even if there's no new version.

That's all I can think for now, report back. =D

Answer (score 0):

I have a Pentium D based Dell 5150 running Win-10 64bit, so I can confirm that the processor will work with 32bit and 64bit Win10. I suggest rather than installing via windows update, use the "media creation tool" and try from a usb drive or dvd.  While you're thinking about the processor, take the time to clean the lint out of the heat sink fins.